# What is the supported method for installing Kubernetes on OpenStack?

Tags: kubernetes, docker-swarm, openstack

If I want to install Kubernetes on OpenStack, is there a supported method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a supported method of doing this. You can install [Magnum (which is itself an OpenStack project)](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Magnum). This will allow you to install any Container Orchestration Engine (COE), including Swarm, Kubernetes, Mesos, and DC/OS. It does this by provisioning an infrastructure cluster of raw OpenStack resources like Nova (the OpenStack compute resource) per-tenant, and installing the COE on the top of it giving you access to the cluster through `kubectl`.

### Links

- https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Magnum
- [OpenStack 2017 Conf - Magnum 101 Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxPUd8ZZuD0)

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, Magnum requires cloud operators to install it first on the Openstack first. Then, users are able to provision kubernetes clusters.

If you are looking to run your own k8s clusters inside VMs, there is [Rancher Openstack operator](https://rancher.com/docs/rke/latest/en/config-options/cloud-providers/openstack/)