# Is there a way for a user to audit their permission levels in OpenStack?

Tags: openstack

In a [comment on the site](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/15349/how-can-i-deploy-a-kubernetes-cluster-onto-openstack-with-terraform?noredirect=1#comment16432_15349) someone has asked me,

> Can you give more info on what kind of permissions [on OpenStack] are we talking about?

I want to answer that question, but I don't know how. Given credentials to Horizon (OpenStack Dashboard) is there a method to tell what my user can and can't do? When I go to the `project/api_access/` I can see only the endpoints I have access to, but not the level of access on each end-point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openstack permissions are not super fun to play around. There are a default set that limits what member/user can do.

Cloud operators are free to customize roles for each Openstack component. Only the operator can tell you if there are custom roles.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC tenants usually don't have privileges to see actual policy definitions, but depending on your configuration you should be able to see some info with `openstack quota`

[Reference doc](https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/xena/cli/command-objects/quota.html)